# Calling stored procedure from c# return different values than MSSMS

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

i'm a novice in T-SQL and i did this Stored Procedure:

If i execute from MSSMS the result is this table

```
Att. Slave AC IPPBX 2020    7   11  8   5   9   9   6   4   0   0   0   0
```

If i execute it from C# with differents commands

```
Att. Slave AC IPPBX 2020    7   18  26  31  40  49  55  59  59  59  59  59
```

As you can see the table called by c# is the sum of first field with second and so on..

```
7+11 = 18

18+8 = 26

26+5 = 31
```

I don't understand why the procedure called by c# sum the values...
Could you help me to find the error?

```
truncate table dbo.ResocontoTicket;
--drop table #tipologiaTable;
select tbl.Tipologia into #tipologiaTable from (Select Distinct(Tk.TipoTicket) as Tipologia From TicketCom Tk) as tbl
DECLARE @Query varchar(max);
DECLARE @TempQuery int;
DECLARE @Index int = 1
DECLARE @TipoTicket varchar(100)
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max)
--DECLARE @Anno varchar(max);
--SET @Anno = '2020';
DECLARE MY_CURSOR CURSOR LOCAL STATIC READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY 
FOR SELECT DISTINCT T.TipoTicket FROM TicketCom T
OPEN MY_CURSOR    

FETCH FIRST FROM MY_CURSOR INTO @TipoTicket
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
---LOOP TIPOTICKET
BEGIN  
SET @Index = 1
set @TipoTicket = REPLACE(@TipoTicket,',','');
set  @Query =''''+@TipoTicket+''''+','+@Anno;
 --LOOP MONTH
WHILE (@index<=12)
BEGIN  
select @TempQuery = (Select Count(Distinct(IdTicket)) QUANTITA  from TicketCom  where (DataChiusura >= @Anno+'-0'+Convert(varchar,@Index)+'-01' and DataChiusura <=  EOMONTH(@Anno+'-'+Convert(varchar,@Index)+'-01')) and  TicketCom.TipoTicket like  @TipoTicket)
set @query = @query+','+''''+Convert(varchar,@TempQuery)+'''';
SET @Index = @Index+1;
END
 -----
SET @SQL = 'insert into dbo.ResocontoTicket (Tipologia,Anno,GENNAIO,FEBBRAIO,MARZO,APRILE,MAGGIO,GIUGNO,LUGLIO,AGOSTO,SETTEMBRE,OTTOBRE,NOVEMBRE,DICEMBRE) values ('+@Query+')'
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
FETCH NEXT FROM MY_CURSOR INTO @TipoTicket 
 
--PRINT @TipoTicket;
END
----
CLOSE MY_CURSOR
DEALLOCATE MY_CURSOR


using (var con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionDb"].ConnectionString))
        {
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("TicketEvasiPerMeseAnnoETipologia", con))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Anno", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = "2020";
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}}
```

[image: Correct Table Executing Stored P. From MSSQL]

[image: This is the table when the c# command is executed]

Comment: This is the stored procedure

'''

Comment: Running a stored procedure, with the same paarameters, from different applications won't return different values unless the data has changed. This either means that the data *has* changed or your aren't running the same SQL.

Comment: Why use a `CURSOR` above and SQL that is open to injection as well? Also your `varchar`'s are missing their length property.

Comment: @Larnu not quite true; there are ambient connection state markers that can influence things, although many of those are fixed/applied when you exec `CREATE PROC` or `ALTER PROC`

Comment: important: your code is incredibly vulnerable right now; `sp_executesql` is only *useful* if you *parameterize* the inner command, i.e. `exec sp_executesql N'select @id', N'@id int', 42;` - without that, you might as well just `exec (@SQL)` (but please don't!)

Comment: I, personally, wouldn't be surprised if the OP has something like a parameter defined as `varchar` (no length) in the Procedure's definition, and is running the batch above outside of the Procedure. Thus, when calling the Procedure the behaviour differs due them using a `varchar(1)` parameter.

Comment: @Larnu plus without a single `order by`, the output isn't exactly deterministic *anyway*...

Comment: We really need a [mre] here, as without one, we can really only guess. We can't run the above batch, as we don't have access to the OP's data or instance, and we don't have the full DDL statement of the Procedure (we're missing the `CREATE`/`ALTER` for example). As a result we don't have a deterministic way to say why the behaviour isn't as they expect.

Comment: I don't see any procedure or any C#

Comment: Now i'll try to do your suggests, remeber i'm a novice :)